# How do I install and use PLINK on Linux? Segmentation fault error

Tags: segmentation-fault, genetics

I downloaded the `plink` zip file from the website (https://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/download.shtml), unzipped, and then execute `plink` in the working directory.

```
$ unzip plink-1.07-x86_64.zip
$ cd plink-1.07-x86_64/
~/plink-1.07-x86_64$ ./plink
```

Traceback:

```
@----------------------------------------------------------@
|        PLINK!       |     v1.07      |   10/Aug/2009     |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  (C) 2009 Shaun Purcell, GNU General Public License, v2  |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  For documentation, citation & bug-report instructions:  |
|        http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/purcell/plink/        |
@----------------------------------------------------------@

Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some luck with PLINK 1.90: https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/

PLINK 1.9 is well maintained and much more efficient compared to PLINK 1.07. Most of the analysis commands in 1.07 are supported in 1.90.